# Sending html Email in CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp

I want to send emails to my users after they get registered in my site. Its like an account-activation mail. I have tried this, but its not working(its my own function from where I am trying to send mails) :

```
public function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$msg,$value,$template){
    $Email=new CakeEmail('smtp');
    $Email->template('template','default')
          ->viewVars(array('value'=>$value))
          ->emailFormat('html')
          ->to($to)
          ->subject($subject)
          ->from(array($from=>'My Site'))
          ->send();
}
```

This is my email.php file's code :

```
<?php
    class EmailConfig{
        public $smtp=array(
           'transport'=>'Smtp',
           'from'=>array('notification@domain.com'=>'My Site'),
           'host'=>HOST,
           'port'=>PORT,
           'timeout'=>30,
           'username'=>'notification@domain.com',
           'password'=>PASSWORD,
           'client'=>null,
           'log'=>false,
           //'charset' => 'utf-8',
           //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
       );
    }
```

Please help me. Is there anything wrong in my code, or, I have to do something else ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you replaced it with dummy data for security's sake, but all those fields in email.php need to contain valid information for an SMTP server. It won't ever work with blatantly false information like "notification@domain.com" as a username.

Not trying to be snarky; just not clear if you understood the default values need to be changed.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the values. I think most of the values are clear here, I think I didn't make mistake with them. I am actually worried about the "port" value(s). My client gave me these info, I was confused where to use what : Incoming Server=Outgoing Server=some info,
•IMAP: Port 993
•POP3: Port 995
•SMTP: Port 465 @ivan